# why is the image not found

Tags: reactjs, image

I want to show the the red image when the switch is false, but i get this error message:
GET http://localhost:5173/welcome_login.svg 404 (Not Found)

```
function color_switch(){
    const red_switch = document.getElementById('welcome-back-div-image-login-id').style.backgroundImage = "url('./background_image_login_red.svg')";
    const dark_switch = document.getElementById('welcome-back-div-image-login-id').style.backgroundImage = "url('./welcome_login.svg')";
    document.getElementById('switch').checked ?  red_switch : dark_switch;
}
[the components](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z5VOb.png)
```

Comment: Code is incomplete to understand please add more code also it's good to always create example snippet for faster resolution

Answer (score 0):

I found it by myself. I didnt use the full path to the file. This is why the server did not find the files.